# Scope displays unexpected puls generator output

Tags: matlab, scope, simulink, clock, pulse

I am having troubles understanding the output of my scope in this simple simulink model:

[image: puls_gen and scope]

I am using a fixed step solver (tried with ode3 and ode8).
`Pulse type` of the puls generator is set to `Sample based` and I varied the `Period` and `Pulse Width`.

First I set the simulation time to 10 and set the puls generator to `Period = 10` and `Puls width = 5`. The output of the scope is as expected:

[image: period=10]

But when I tried with simulation time 10,000 and the puls generator with `Period = 1,000` and `Puls width = 500` it seems my scope is wrong:

[image]

Why is the first falling edge at 5,500? I used the Autoscale button every time.

Using sim time 100,000 and `Period = 10,000` and `Puls width = 5,000` I don't even get a single falling edge:

[image]

Even with longer simulation time there seems to be a single rising edge at the end of the scope window.

What am I doing wrong? Is the scope not suitable for such long simulation times using fixed step solver? Or is it not "safe" to use the Autoscale button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the plots you show are correct.  Simulink is fine with long simulation times.  It is "safe" to use the Autoscale button.

By default a scope is set to only display the last 5000 simulation time steps.  Since your model is taking a step size of 1s (this is based on using the default step size of the Pulse Generator, which is 1s), in your second plot you are only seeing points from t=5000 to t=10000 (so the first down step ***in that time period*** is at 5500), and in your third plot you are only seeing points from t=95000 to t=100000 (which is a period in which the value of the pulse is low/zero).

To see all simulation times, open the Scope block's parameters (by clicking the button with a picture of a cog on it), go to the History tab, and deselect the *Limit data points to last:* check box.

Then rerun your simulation and press the autoscale button.  You'll then see what (I think) you are expecting.